# Where is ByteArrayOutputStream's data stored, on the RAM or on the hard disk?

Tags: java, io, inputstream, outputstream

In the code below, where is `ByteArrayOutputStream`'s data stored, on the RAM or on the hard disk?

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream(12);

while( bOutput.size()!= 10 ) {
    // Gets the inputs from the user
    bOutput.write("hello".getBytes());
}
```

Comment: The ByteArrayOutputStream class stream creates a buffer in memory[ram]. For performance critical code try to use ByteBuffer instead of ByteArrayOutputStream. If using synchronization  and ByteArrayOutputStream together, get rid of synchronization part.

Answer (score 4):

That object will be allocated into the JAVA Heap, which will be in RAM, however, based on how your system is configured it is possible that if your ram is exhausted it might be moved to a swap partition on the disk.  This has nothing to do with the JVM's allocations, but how the operating system allocates/manages memory.

The simple answer is: RAM

Answer (score 0):

You store it in an array (byte[] b) and every variable is stored in ram!

The stream itsself only stores the data in the array. And the stream is also saved in ram!

Comment: data written to bOutput  will also store on ram only ?

Comment: the output stream is an object!And if you write to it it will stored in the object -> Ram

Comment: thanks , in my proj i have to download huge files like 10gb ,4 or 5 at a time and one download done i have to upload them, in my dev machine i am getting out of memory with 8gb ram but in qa with 16gb i am not getting why

Comment: If you want to recive all data save it on the Hard Disk and use a FileOutputStream